# Mongoose .env returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, dotenv

I am setting up my database connection using a MEVN stack but I am getting the following error;

```
The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"
```

If I try console log process.env.DATABASE_URL it just returns undefined. What have I done wrong here's my code;

index.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import Express from 'express';
import Mongoose from 'mongoose';

dotenv.config();

const app = Express();

Mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.listen(3000, () => {
    // console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    console.log('server started on port 3000');
});
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://reece:<password>@mevn-tutorial-cluster-egjs6.mongodb.net/auth?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I removed my password for obvious reasons

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);`?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a .env file in the root dir of your application.
in the .env file you should have key value separate by equal sign.
As example:

```
secret=foo
DATABASE_URL=bar:pwd@localhost.com
```

As the documentation states:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Yeah turns out I had it in my server folder. It's now in the root and working thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have not used template literals for mongoose connections.

Try this:

`Mongoose.connect(${process.env.DATABASE_URL}, { useNewUrlParser: true });`

to get actual `.env` variable to your Javascript snippet.

Answer (score 1):

**I made this mistake, and you shouldn't do it either.**

Make sure your.env file is in the root. Check the path of .env before proceeding ahead.

```
npm install dotenv

require("dotenv").config(); //Keep this at top of your file
```

**In .env file, add**

```
ADMIN_ID="mongoose://******************" //YOUR URL ADDRESS WITH PASSWORD
```

**In app.js file,**

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.ADMIN_ID);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Make sure your.env file is in the root. Check the path of .env before proceeding ahead.
this is it

Answer (score 0):

```
dotenv.config({ path: "config.env" });

    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    })
```

use path. it'll work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).